# Angular 2 CLI insert component inside existing directory tree (shift other components down)

Tags: angular, angular2-components

> TL:DR - Is there a way to add a component above an existing component:
>   meaning in the file path of the exiting component, not next to it?

Lets say I have an Angular project with the following simple tree structure:

```
app/parent/child1
app/parent/child2
```

But now as my project grows I see I want to add another component (to make another branch), above my existing directory

```
app/parent/i_am_OLD_here/child1
app/parent/i_am_OLD_here/child2
app/parent/i_am_NEW_here/child3
app/parent/i_am_NEW_here/child4
```

If I am in directory `app/parent` and I do:
`ng g component i_am_NEW_here` I will just of coarse get:

```
app/parent/child1
app/parent/child2
app/parent/i_am_NEW_here
```

which then means that I have to create `child1` and `child2` in directory `app/parent/i_am_new_here` and then copy all the data inside the old `child1` and child2` components to the new ones AND change all the imports in the components AND the module components (which is still kind of fine if you have only two components, but what if you have many more)?

I do not see anything like this in the [CLI documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#development-hints-for-working-on-angular-cli) and have run into this problem quite a few times. **Obviously** one of the answers can be to plan my project better, but how do I know what features I (or a client) may want 3 months from now?

Answer (score 2):

With the angular CLI it is possible to specify a subfolder prefix to generate your component into.

For example:

`ng g component <any_nested_path>/i_am_NEW_here --dry-run`

Run this as a dry run and it will show you the resources being created in the `any_nested_path` directory. Remove the dry-run flag to actually create the component.

Comment: Awesome. Just to add to the answer the default folder taken is src/app

Comment: I have tried this a few ways now, and want to make sure of something. This will only create the new component where you specify in the sub folder (like my 3rd piece of code), it will not move all the already created components down (like my second piece of code)?

Comment: This will only affect the creation of a new component and should have no side-effects on existing components.

Comment: OK, maybe it did not come out correctly in my question, but I am actually looking for something that will specifically affect the existing components. Is there a way to add a component above an existing component, meaning in the file path of the exiting component, not next to it...

Comment: Sorry, this can't currently be done in the CLI. There is an open issue here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900. Someone has rolled their own tool to do renaming which might help https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-rn. Alternatively, any reasonable IDE will be able to refactor/rename a component into a subfolder.